# get N latest records

Tags: meteor

How do I get the N latest records with meteors mongodb?

I know I could do it like this with normal mongodb: `db.foo.find().sort({_id:1});`, so I thought this would work with meteor: `collection.find({chatroom: Session.get("room")}, {sort: {_id:1}, limit: N })`.

But this only returns some "random" documents. I guess they are the 10 records with the lowest _id value, like _id= aaaaa and _id= aaaab.

What am I missing here? In normal mongodb its supereasy?!

Comment: or you can have a field like timestamp then sort by your timestamp

Comment: yea, but that shouldnt be necessary with mongodb because I can get that from the _id?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using `$natural` sort specifier of mongoDB.

```
collection.find({chatroom: Session.get("room")}, {sort: {$natural : 1}, limit: N });
```

The natural order is an order in which the database stores documents on disk. Typically an insertion order.

I use `date_created` value for sorting normally. Because the natural order changes sometimes, when you perform `update` operations on existing documents.

Comment: ah ok, ill create a date_created instead then. Great explanation why!

Comment: can I ask one more question? :) Now if I sort them and render them they end up like this:

(top)
newest
new
old
oldest
(bottom)
.. but I want the reverse order so that the newest shows at the bottom, how can I do that? Ive tried using both date_created: 1 and -1 with limit(10). But when using "1" I only see the 10 oldest :/

Answer (score 4):

I got stuck on limit as well (I reckon it's a Meteor bug). I ended up writing this function:

```
Template.content.messages = function () {
    var items = Messages.find({}, {sort: {timestamp : 1} }).fetch();
    return items.slice(-15);
}
```

Timestamp field is defined like this:

```
timestamp: new Date().getTime()
```